# Model builder - Create a new File GDB then convert a CSV into a file GDB table in new File GDB

Tags: modelbuilder, iterator, model

I am trying to create a model to create a new file GDB.  The model would then iterate through a folder of CSV tables, convert them to file GDB tables and add them to the newly created File GDB.  I need to link the newly created file GDB to the copy rows function so it automatically puts any tables into the new file GDB.

[image: My model so far.]

Comment: I don't understand, what is your question?  It at least appears like you have a handle on the situation and have a model built to meet your needs.  Are you getting a specific error message, or what is the problem or question you're posting about.  Please edit your question to explain the situation and give a specific question we can give specific answers to.

Comment: I edited my question.  Hopefully my problem is clearer now.  The new file GDB name will change every time the model is run and there can't be any user input for most of the model so making a model parameter for the output table location is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look into using model builder's in-line variable substitution properties to accomplish this.  You can get info about that here http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Examples_of_inline_model_variable_substitution/002w0000005w000000/ (I've included a link to the v 10.0 help as I don't know the version you're using and not that much in this topic has changed to my knowledge recently).  Anyway, using in-line variable substitution, you should be able to use the "Processing File GDB" output you have in the model above as the beginning part of the output table's full path.  You might have to play with this a bit to get exactly what you want, but for example it might be something like `%Processing File GDB%\%Name%` as the output table.

Hope that helps, let me know if you have any questions.